# Xamarin close Android application on back button

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I tried 3 different ways

```
if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
    System.Environment.Exit(0);

public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    Finish();
}

public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.Back)
    {
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
            return true;
    }
    return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}
```

None of the above seems to be working

Comment: Old question, and probably stupid, the `public override void OnBackPressed` should be on the `Activity` you are currently on, not just on `MainActivity`

Comment: @RosdiKasim Why would I have 2 activities ? I only had 1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use a [DepedencyService for closing an app](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18156/how-to-close-my-app) when your physical back button is pressed:

In your UI (PCL), do the following:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
   if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
       DependencyService.Get<IAndroidMethods>().CloseApp();

   return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

Also create an Interface (in your UI PCL):

```
public interface IAndroidMethods
{
    void CloseApp();
}
```

Now implement the Android-specific logic in your Android project:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AndroidMethods))]
namespace Your.Namespace
{
   public class AndroidMethods : IAndroidMethods
   {
       public void CloseApp()
       {
            Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: In which file I need to write Android-specific logic ??

Comment: @TarunSeera Just create a new file in your Android project. Declaring the `assembly` attribute in the class to ensure the Android-specific logic is registered in the `DependencyService` ([read more here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/)). This essentially means that you can place the file wherever you want in your Android project. The `DependencyService` will take care of the rest.

Comment: Can you also suggest how to make Left align text in Button (Xamarin Forms)

Comment: Process.KillProcess(Process.MyPid()); Please update the syntax

Answer (score 4):

If you want to exit from App without killing and back to home screen, so that if you want to resume it back from where it get closed. you can do implementing as follows in your related activity.

```
  public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
        startMain.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryHome);
        startMain.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        StartActivity(startMain);

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice solution.Can you explain more?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this code, it works from my side. Hope this code helps you.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            var result = await DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Do you really want to exit the application?", "Yes", "No");
            if (result)
            {
                if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
                {
                    Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: TargetPlatform is obsolete.... use:
 if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your activity:

```
this.FinishAffinity();
```

Good luck!!

Comment: this should be in comment

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{           
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => 
    {
        var res = await this.DisplayAlert("Do you really want to exit the application?", "","Yes", "No").ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (res) System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().CloseMainWindow();
    });           
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    Finish();
    Android.OS.Process.KillProcess (Android.OS.Process.MyPid ());
}
```

Comment: `OnBackPressed()` doesn't trigger at all for me

Comment: Have you put the OnBackPressed() in the mainActivity?

Comment: @IdoT Of course I have. There is no other place to put it in

Answer (score 0):

```
Finish();
```

Worked for me. Executed from the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

You also can ask the user to confirm exit App:

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    RunOnUiThread(
        async () =>
        {
            var isCloseApp = await AlertAsync(this, "NameOfApp", "Do you want to close this app?", "Yes", "No");

            if (isCloseApp)
            {
                var activity = (Activity)Forms.Context;
                activity.FinishAffinity();
            }
        });
}

public Task<bool> AlertAsync(Context context, string title, string message, string positiveButton, string negativeButton)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    using (var db = new AlertDialog.Builder(context))
    {
        db.SetTitle(title);
        db.SetMessage(message);
        db.SetPositiveButton(positiveButton, (sender, args) => { tcs.TrySetResult(true); });
        db.SetNegativeButton(negativeButton, (sender, args) => { tcs.TrySetResult(false); });
        db.Show();
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

[Xamarin.Android await AlertDialog.Builder](https://medium.com/@dannyc/xamarin-android-await-alertdialog-builder-42d9c861e37a)